# How can I include given Handlebars helpers in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

On Github, many Handlebars helpers are presented. You can find them [here](https://gist.github.com/slindberg/9924116).

I'd like to use them, but have no Idea, how to include them. The code is looking as it's javascript (files are ending with .js ...), but words like 'import','export','default' are confusing me.

As I understand (guess), I have to include the *if-condition.js* at first. Later, the other (included) files refer to this file.

But when I do this, the console throws an Error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word* .

Has anyone an idea, how to get these codes working?

Answer (score 0):

`import` and `export` are keywords for the upcoming [module syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3amodules) in the next version of Javascript. You can use them today by using a [transpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) to convert it to normal ES5 syntax.

However, if you're only using a few helpers, it's very easy to 'transpile' them by hand. Instead of exporting the function, just pass it to a `Ember.Hanldebars.registerBoundHelper` call. Here's the `if-condition` helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('if-condition', function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var options = args.pop();
    var context = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;

    if (!options.conditional) {
        throw new Error("A conditional callback must be specified when using the if-condition helper");
    }

    // Gather all bound property names to pass in order to observe them
    var properties = options.types.reduce(function(results, type, index) {
        if (type === 'ID') {
            results.push(args[index]);
        }
        return results;
    }, []);

    // Resolve actual values for all params to pass to the conditional callback
    var normalizer = function() {
        return Ember.Handlebars.resolveParams(context, args, options);
    };

    // This effectively makes the helper a bound helper
    // NOTE: 'content' path is used so that multiple properties can be bound to using the `childProperties` argument,
    // however this means that it can only be used with a controller that proxies values to the 'content' property
    return Ember.Handlebars.bind.call(context, 'content', options, true, options.conditional, normalizer, properties);
});
```

Comment: including the js works, nut using the helper in my template, an error is thrown:

"Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks."

Comment: I found this: [link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zelib/1/edit).
Very similar to your code. This works fine.

Comment: unfortunately, I had to cancel mark, that the Question is answered.

If I use "registerHelper", they're working fine until a property changes. Then, the view won't update. Seems, like I have to use "registerBoundHelper", but using it, the posted error will occur.